# Can you use std::bind (or something else) to change return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

Say I've got a function,

```cpp
bool my_func(bool input_val) { return !input_val; }
```

and I want to pass it around as a function that returns void and takes nothing, so it would be something like:

```cpp
bool the_truth = true;
void func_taking_a_void_func(std::function<void()> void_func) {};
func_taking_a_void_func([the_truth]() -> void { my_func(the_truth); });
```

I first tried using `std::bind`, but naturally the compiler couldn't use `my_func` since it returned a bool instead of void.

```cpp
func_taking_a_void_func(std::bind(my_func, the_truth));
```

Is it possible to do something like a `std::bind_and_ignore_return_type`, without just wrappin the call to the function with a lambda? I'm using C++11 on VS2013, but anything else is good too.

Comment: what is the problem with the lambda function?

Comment: I pitched my guess already, but "the compiler says something about the function returning a value, and being unable to convert" is not detailed enough for a reliable answer. When you're looking for help with a compiler error, you should always post a self-contained snippet that reproduces your issue, and you should always post the exact error that you get when you try to build it.

Comment: What is the signature of `func_taking_a_void_func`. `func_taking_a_void_func(void(*)())`? Please post working code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _"says something about the function returning a value, and being unable to convert."_, paste it.

Comment: @alfC `void func_taking_a_void_func(std::function<void()>)`, I should have had that in there first, thanks!

Comment: @zneak I wasn't looking for help with a compiler error as much as I was trying to figure out to avoid using a lambda for that `func_taking_a_void_func` call. I provided the std::bind line to show that std::bind doesn't work, rather than get help for solving that error.

Comment: @alfC no real problem, was only wondering if there was an alternative

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `std::bind` or a lambda that captures a variable to pass it to a function that expects a function pointer. Lambdas are convertible to function pointers when they do not capture any variable; the result of `std::bind` never is.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what it is your problem, but anyway, this doesn't use the lambda.

```
#include<type_traits>

template<class F>
struct adapt{
    bool arg_;
    F f_;
    adapt(bool arg, F f) : arg_{arg}, f_{f}{}
    void operator()() const{f_();}
};

template<class F> adapt<F> make_adapt(bool b, F f){return adapt<F>(b, f);}

template<class F> int func_taking_a_void_func(F&& f){
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f()), void>{}, "!");
    return 5;
}

bool my_func(bool input_val) { return !input_val; }

int main(){
    bool the_truth = true;
    func_taking_a_void_func(make_adapt(the_truth, my_func));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the argument `bool input_val` has to come from *somewhere*.

If you really just have one flag, you can just make two functions

```
void my_true_func() { my_func(true); }
void my_false_func() { my_func(false); }
```

And choose one or the other based on the flag.

Otherwise `bool input_val` must be a global/thread-local variable accessible from anywhere.

You can't use lambda capture, doing so would turn the lambda from a function into a struct. But if the solutions above don't help, the only way to go is to work with functors instead of function pointers.

Note that `std::bind` cannot capture anything and is largely obsolete since the introduction of lambdas.